# How to properly filter model to update Plotly graph in Django?

Tags: html, django, plotly, django-filter

Good day!

I am trying based on a small example
build a graph plotly
Based on data from the model

I then try to make the date interval selectable.
Created a form and built it into the template.

From this form in the template, I get data by start and end date in the views code.

Next, I'm trying to filter the data from the model based on the date range retrieved from the template.

And based on the filtered data from the model, "update" the graph on the template.

But I get an error - Plotly does not get the necessary lists of data to update the plot.

If you have any information, I will be very grateful.
I have already used many options for solving the issue, but unfortunately nothing works for me.
I would really appreciate any help.
You may be able to find errors in this code.

```
ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references or list of columns for both `x` and `y`.
```

templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'chart' %}">

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button>Submit</button>

    </form>

    {{ chart|safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

forms

```
from datetime import date
from django import forms
from .models import *


class DateForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    end = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Monitoring(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    nomerkot = models.IntegerField()
    nomerkotla = models.IntegerField()
    tnv = models.IntegerField()
    rashod = models.IntegerField()
    temppod = models.IntegerField()
    tempobr = models.IntegerField()
    tempuhod = models.IntegerField()
    davlgas = models.FloatField()
    davlvos = models.IntegerField()
    virob = models.IntegerField()
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import plotly.express as px

import csv
from datetime import date
from itertools import islice
from django.conf import settings

import pandas as pd

from .models import *

from .forms import *


def chart(request):
    dict_from_csv = pd.read_csv('demo/dannye.csv', header=0, sep=';', decimal=",")
    dict_from_csv['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dict_from_csv['date'], dayfirst=True)
    dict_from_csv['davlgas'] = pd.to_numeric(dict_from_csv['davlgas'])

    monitoring = Monitoring.objects.all()

    date_x = dict_from_csv['date'].to_numpy()
    date_y = dict_from_csv['temppod'].to_numpy().tolist()

    start = request.GET.get('start')
    start = pd.to_datetime(start)
    end = request.GET.get('end')
    end = pd.to_datetime(end)


    sortirovka = Monitoring.objects.filter(date__gte=start,date__lte=end)

    fig = px.line(
        x=[c.date for c in sortirovka],
        y=[c.temppod for c in sortirovka]
    )

    fig.update_layout(title = {
        "font_size": 22,
        "xanchor": "center",
        "x": 0.5
    })

    chart = fig.to_html()

    context = {'chart': chart, 'form': DateForm()}
    return render(request, 'demo/chart.html', context)
```

urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import forms


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.chart, name='chart')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a django problem. The problem lays only within these lines:

```
    sortirovka = Monitoring.objects.filter(date__gte=start,date__lte=end)

    fig = px.line(
        x=[c.date for c in sortirovka],
        y=[c.temppod for c in sortirovka]
    )
```

You are passing a by list comprehension created list to `x` and `y`. I am not sure, but I do not think a list is considerate "array-like" by plotly.

> x (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in
> data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this
> column or array_like are used to position marks along the x axis in
> cartesian coordinates. Either x or y can optionally be a list of
> column references or array_likes, in which case the data will be
> treated as if it were ‘wide’ rather than ‘long’. ([source](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line))

Try to create the plot separately beforehand with a list. I think it does not work.

Guess if you would input a numpy array or a pandas series it would be fine. In [the examples](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/) they always input a dataframe and `x` and `y` are pointers to the columns that you are referring too.

What just came to my mind - **try this first**:
I guess `x` and `y` accept a list containing multiple lists. Because that's how you input multiple dataseries. You only have one, so try the following:

```
    fig = px.line(
        x=[[c.date for c in sortirovka],],
        y=[[c.temppod for c in sortirovka],]
    )
```